# How to build a linked list, that every node will have a random int value, but the total values sum and the number of nodes will be fixed in advance?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, linked-list

I've started building something like this:

```
class Node{
    Node next,prev;
    int val;
    Node(int val, Node prev, Node next){
        this.val = val;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

....

```
 public void buildRandomPath(int size, int total){
    road = new Node[size];
    int tmp = (int)(Math.random()*(double)(total/size));
    total = total-tmp;
    road[0] = new Node(tmp,road[size-1],road[1]);
    for (int i = 1; i < size-1; i++){
        tmp = (int)(Math.random()*(double)(total/size-i));
        total = total-tmp;
        road[i] = new Node(tmp1,road[i-1],road[i+1]);
    }
    tmp = (int)(Math.random()*(double)(total));
    total = total-tmp;
    road[size-1] = new Node(tmp,road[size-2],road[0]);
}
```

It is totally not the right algorithm, but this is the general idea i'm heading for

Comment: It basically depends on what additional constraints are given. E.g. how the random distribution of nodes should be? Or has any possible list have the same probability? ...

Comment: In what way can both all values be random and the sum be deterministic? It seems to me at least one value has to be deterministically dependent on all other values, no?

Comment: @G.Bach Random does not automatically mean independent. In the given case the deterministic sum just reduces the number of random degrees by one.

Comment: @Howard I assumed that random in this context meant "there are more than one possible outcomes with positive probability", which doesn't apply to the last value that is chosen. Of course probabilities don't have to be independent, but calling a certain event (i.e. one that has probability 1) random is at least contextually misleading.

Comment: @G.Bach Of course it is not. Also the last value has more than one possible outcome. And additionally it totally depends on your interpretation what "the last value" is. So it is perfectly valid to call it random.

Comment: @Howard Thinking about it, I agree with you; my thoughts were a little overly restrictive.

Answer (score 2):

For a uniform random answer (assuming the implicit non-negativity constraint): generate `nodeCount - 1` pairwise distinct integers between `0` inclusive and `sum + nodeCount - 1` exclusive. Sort these, prepend `-1`, and append `sum + nodeCount - 1`. Return the difference sequence minus one.

Example: `nodeCount = 4` and `sum = 10`. Generate integers.

```
5 2 12
```

Sort, prepend, append.

```
-1 2 5 12 13
```

Difference sequence.

```
3 3 7 1
```

Minus one.

```
2 2 6 0
```

Implementation notes: you need to special case `nodeCount == 0` if that's a possibility. To generate integers with no duplicates: if `sum` is small compared to `nodeCount`, then use a partial Fisher--Yates shuffle. Otherwise, sample `nodeCount - 1` integers with replacement and repeat until there are no duplicates.

Comment: I don't see how the question implies non-negativity and an upper bound for the values as constraints.

Comment: I see; either way, the solution you give can be used to generate unbounded values by picking random numbers to add to one element of the sequence and subtract from another, so the bounds are easy to do away with anyway.

Comment: @G.Bach I don't really understand, but for negative and nonnegative `int`s, Peter's solution is simpler and works great given that Java wraps `int` addition.

Comment: I think he's missing the final node on his path though, or am I misreading it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum to be a particular total, you can have a remaining total and make the last element that value. e..g

Make the nodes have random values X1, X2, ... Xn-1, total - SumOf(X1, ... Xn-1)  This will ensure the total is always `total`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate n values, the sum of which is S, you could generate n random doubles between 0 and 1, then divide them so they total 1. You then multiply the values by S. If the numbers have to be integers, some additional work may be needed to handle rounding properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
double runningTotal = total;
Random rand = new Random();
road = new double[size];
while(runningTotal > 0) {
    double temp = rand.nextDouble(); // return [0, 1)
    if(temp > runningTotal) {
        temp = runningTotal;
        runningTotal = 0.0;
    } else {
        runningTotal -= temp;
    }
    road[rand.nextInt(size)] += temp;
}
```

You can replace `temp = rand.nextDouble()` with `temp = rand.nextDouble / scalingFactor` (where e.g. scalingFactor = 10) to increase the uniformity and reduce the probability that any nodes will end up equaling 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Node[] buildRandomPath(int size, int total){
    Node[] road = new Node[size];
    int tmp = (int)(Math.random()*(double)(total/size));
    if(tmp==0)
        tmp=1;
    total = total-tmp;
    road[0] = new Node(tmp,road[size-1],road[1]);
    int tmp1=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < size-1; i++){
        tmp1 = (int)(Math.random()*(double)(total/size-i));
        if(tmp1==0)
            tmp1=1;
        total = total-tmp1;
        if(total>0)
            road[i] = new Node(tmp1,road[i-1],road[i+1]);
        else
            road[i] = new Node(0,road[i-1],road[i+1]);
    }
    road[size-1] = new Node(total,road[size-2],road[0]);
    return road;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


class Node{
    Node next,prev;
    int val;
}

public class temp {

    public Node[] buildRandomPath(int size, int total){

        Node[] road = new Node[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < road.length; i++) {
            road[i]=new Node();
        } 

         int tmp = (int)(Math.random()*(double)(total/size));
        if(tmp==0)
            tmp=1;
        total = total-tmp;
        road[0].val=tmp;
        road[0].next=road[1];
        road[0].prev=road[size-1];  
        int tmp1=0;
        for (int i = 1; i < size-1; i++){
            tmp1 = (int)(Math.random()*(double)(total/size-i));
            if(tmp1==0)
                tmp1=1;
            total = total-tmp1;
            road[i].next=road[i+1];
            road[i].prev=road[i-1];
            if(total>0)
                road[i].val=tmp1;
            else
                road[i].val=0;
        }
        road[size-1].val=total;
        road[size-1].next=road[0];
        road[size-1].prev=road[size-2];
        return road;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        temp t=new temp();
        Node[] node=t.buildRandomPath(10, 500);
        int i=0;
        for (Node node2 : node) {
            i=i+node2.val;

    }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```